# ubuntu one signon problems

Tags: 13.04, ubuntu-one

I am trying to log into ubuntu one but it keeps telling me

```
GET/HEAD request should not include body
```

What does this mean and how can I sign in?

Comment: Do you have any PPAs enabled, or software installed from source (`python-oauthlib` in particular), or are you actually running this on a different distribution?

Comment: @dobey I have probably a ppa or two I added to download some software.  I have that python lib installed.  `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oauthlib
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauthlib
/usr/share/pyshared/oauthlib`

Answer (score 4):

You have a newer version of `python-oauthlib` installed from source to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7` directory, which breaks API compatibility from the version that is shipped in Ubuntu 13.04. This API break causes the error you posted in your question. If you remove the version you installed from source, and rely on the system `python-oauthlib` package instead, then Ubuntu One will work fine.

Comment: do you know if there is a future plan on fixing this in Ubuntu's end?